# Inno Setup : Unicode in the language files are not being converted and displayed as it is

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup version 6 and earlier I was using unofficial translation files from Inno Setup website for Korea and Chinese traditional languages they worked fine but we have our own translation team which verified the translation and converted them into Unicode. But the characters are not being converted on final setup and being displayed as it is.

[image: Setup file]

[Chinese traditional Language file can be downloaded from this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uqmn9pxVIi2rBe0U5T3XnmNQPs9pU11X)

**UPDATE:**  Seems like Inno Setup does not have support for UTF-16 ([Unicode Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode))

Is there any option within Inno Setup to make it work?

Comment: It seems like this ISL file you share is corrupted / wrongly encoded as it looks exactly as what you show in the [picture](https://imgur.com/a/YdPaLdX)

Answer (score 2):

Your ISL file has been wrongly converted to UTF-8 and contains only code characters instead of real ones.

[image]

I have converted few strings and resaved the file:
[image]
[image]